# Switching array to vector inside struct, how to handle file io byte alignment

Tags: c++, struct, file-io, memory-alignment

We used to have a structure:

```
const int NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS = 10;  
struct myStruct1
{
    uint32_t var1;
    uint64_t var2;
    uint32_t elements[NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS];
};
```

However, going forward we want the number of elements to be variable.  I think I would best do this as:

```
struct myStruct2
{
    uint32_t var1;
    uint64_t var2;
    std::vector<uint32_t> elements;
    myStruct2(int len){ elements.resize(len);};
};
```

For reading/writing from a file, we used to simply do:

```
myStruct1 ms1;
std::ofstream outfile(FILENAME,std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::binary);
outfile.write((const char*)&ms1,sizeof(myStruct1));
outfile.close();

myStruct1 msread1;
std::ifstream infile(FILENAME, std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);
infile.read((char *)&msread1, sizeof(myStruct1));
infile.close();
```

Obviously I can't do that anymore for the vector version. So, I would have to read element by element.

```
myStruct2 msread2(NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS);
std::ifstream infile(FILENAME, std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);
infile.read((char *)&msread2.var1, sizeof(uint32_t));
infile.read((char *)&msread2.var2, sizeof(uint64_t));
for (int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS; i++)
{
    infile.read((char *)&msread2.elements[i], sizeof(uint32_t));
}
infile.close();
```

However, this runs into the problem of byte alignment... there is 4 bytes of padding after var1 in the struct (and in the file).  Reading var1 then var2 doesn't skip this pad.

I could use #pragma pack(1) both for writing and for reading.  However I would like the reader to be compatible with old files which were created with the padding.

I could manually have a seek of 4 bytes (or read a dummy 4 byte variable) after reading var1.  But I feel there's probably better ways.

I could put var1 and var2 in their own struct within myStruct1 or myStruct2, and read them together, maybe this is a bit cleaner for io but then accessing them would have an extra step eg ms1.headvars.var1 instead of just ms1.var1. (more changes throughout the codebase)

Any recommendations on a nicer solution?

Comment: I put a header on all files I write that contains at least a file version number. When I change the format I can maintain backward compatibility in the reader while the writer only writes the current version. Changes to size/padding/types/whatever is easily dealt with. Since you probably do not have that I'd add an explicit dummy or padding variable in the padding space and have the reader read it like all the rest. You don't need to read each vector element one by one. After you resize it you can just `infile.read((char *)msread2.elements.data(), NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS * sizeof(uint32_t));`

Comment: For all my types I do not rely on being able to serialize them directly from memory. Aside from the fact that the compiler is free to insert padding as it wishes (requiring you to pack) it locks your design in stone, as you are now experiencing. Part of the entire point of encapsulation is to allow the inner workings of something to change without impacting anything that Uses it. To this end, even for simple types I write serialization and deserialization methods that output exactly what I want it represented as. It is a lot less work than it sounds and has many benefits.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply write a vector binary to disk; it contains internally the size, used, and a pointer to the real data which is dynamically allocated (and whatever else the compiler-maker enjoyed to put there; in any sequence). You would get at best the pointer value written into your file.

Instead, you need to write the size, and then its content in two steps: `v.size()`, and `v.data()`.
When reading them back, you read first the size, prepare a vector, and then read the data back: `v.resize(size);`, then read into `v.data()` [yes, you can write into `v.data()`!]

Comment: The question already acknowledged I can not directly write the vector binary.  This solution would work fine if starting from scratch, but for now has the major drawback of not being able to handle previously written files.